# Masonry with modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm trying to open a modal when I click a picture on a masonry.

I've put all together some code pieces and I reached this result but the problem is that the modal works only if I put an `id` on one image at the time.  If I put the same `id` on another image, the modal doesn't work.

I need to have the modal working on all images, and not just on one. any advice?

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<!-- masonry html -->
<div class="P-portfolio-masonry-cont cont-1400 m-a mb-125">
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img id="myImg" src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" alt="A windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" alt="A windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" alt="A windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/suspension-bridge.jpg" alt="A windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" alt="A windmill" />
  </div>
</div>


<!-- modal html -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing it works. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `onClick` to all elements (images) - `id`s are supposed to be unique within a DOM but you can use `class`es instead.

```
// this returns a collection of elements (
var imgArray = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb");

// iterate thru the collection and add event listener
for (let img of imgArray) {
  img.onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.alt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
};
```

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var imgArray = document.getElementsByClassName("thumb");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (let img of imgArray) {
  img.onclick = function() {
    console.log(this.alt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.title = this.title;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
};

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.thumb {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- masonry html -->
<div class="P-portfolio-masonry-cont cont-1400 m-a mb-125">
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" title="A windmill"  alt="A windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" title="B windmill" alt="b windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" title="C windmill" alt="c windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/suspension-bridge.jpg" title="D windmill" alt="d windmill" />
  </div>
  <div class="P-portfolio-m-c-foto">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://assets.codepen.io/12005/windmill.jpg" title="F windmill" alt="f windmill" />
  </div>
</div>


<!-- modal html -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

*Updated to add title to images (to display while on hover) - per comments*

Comment: You need to add an event listener to the modal’s close button.

Comment: Do a search on stackoverflow and you are likely to find the same question already in here

Comment: I also need to see the caption text when i'm in hover on an image. How can i do it?

Comment: Please ask a separate question.  Typically, adding a `title` attribute with the caption as value is enough to display something on hover - for example, `<img src="..." title="Caption goes here" class="..." alt="..."/>`